# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 cursor

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am getting the following error:

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested,
>   with a size of 0.

From this code:

```
  public Lirik getLirik(String id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MUPUH, 
                             new String[] { KEY_ID, JUDUL, KEY_MUPUH }, 
                             KEY_ID + "=?",
                             new String[] {
                               String.valueOf(id)
                             }, 
                             null, 
                             null, 
                             null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Lirik lirik = new Lirik(cursor.getString(1),
                            cursor.getString(2));
    db.close();
    return lirik;
}
```

and this class `ViewMupuh` :
error on : `Lirik lirik = db.getLirik(position);`

```
public class ViewMupuh extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static String position = null;

    private TextView textJudul, textLirik;
    private Button bUpdate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_mupuh);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        position = intent.getStringExtra("position");
        if (position != null) {
            Log.d("value of position", position);
        }
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
        Lirik lirik = db.getLirik(position);
        textJudul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.judul_details);
        textJudul.setText(lirik.getJudul());
        textLirik = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lirikdetails);
        textLirik.setText(lirik.getLirik());

        bUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bupdatedetails);
        bUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditLirik.class);
        intent.putExtra("position value", position);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: You should be sure to format your code cleanly - it will help you spot many errors very easily. Also, please include the *line number* of the `OutOfBoundsException`, which probably points to the offending code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems in your code. First of all, you are calling `cursor.moveToFirst()` twice innecesarily:

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) // <-- First call
    cursor.moveToFirst();                   // <-- Second call
```

Also, you are trying to get data from the cursor even if the cursor is null or it has retrieved no data:

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
    cursor.moveToFirst();

Lirik lirik = new Lirik(cursor.getString(1), 
        cursor.getString(2)); // <-- cursor can be null here
```

Anyway, you are leaving resources open. You never close `cursor` and if there is any problem, `db` is not closed either. I suggest to rewrite your `getLirik()` function this way:

```
public Lirik getLirik(final String id) {
    Lirik lirik = null;

    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;

    try {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query(TABLE_MUPUH, new String[] { KEY_ID, JUDUL,
                KEY_MUPUH }, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { id }, null,
                null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            lirik = new Lirik(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        // Do something with the Exception (Log, raise, ...)
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }

    return lirik;
}
```

If you do so, take into account that you can get null when calling `getLirik()`, so, in your `ViewMupuh.onCreate()` you should check for it to avoid further errors:

```
textJudul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.judul_details);
textLirik = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lirikdetails);

DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
Lirik lirik = db.getLirik(position);

if (lirik != null) {
    textJudul.setText(lirik.getJudul());
    textLirik.setText(lirik.getLirik());
}
```

Also take into account that all the hints point to that there is no record in your database that matches the id you are querying for (maybe your database is empty?)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are more than one problem here. The first problem is that the cursor does not have any row in it. The second problem is the following.

```
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    Lirik lirik = new Lirik(cursor.getString(1),
            cursor.getString(2));
    db.close();
    return lirik;
```

there is no curly braces around the if statement. As a result, in the case where the cursor has no row, it is still executing `Lirik lirik = new Lirik(cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2));`

Please make sure your database has the information you need.

Comment: cursor.moveToFirst(); is called double when you use it in your if-statement aswell.

Comment: That's what I want I mean by highlight that block of code. @Jordy